# Question on date fields in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

When I use a date field in a VF page and try to do validation and return a validation error - such as, if date can't be greater than today's date, the date format automatically changes to something like,

Jul 20 2015 00:00:00

and when I try to submit that again, I get an error that states that values can't be converted from text to date. Even when I try to do any formatting within the controller and assign it back to the date field as mm/dd/yyyy, it still only shows in the above format.

Does anyone know how to keep the date format as mm/dd/yyyy or whatever format is acceptable when the post back occurs and I do not get this error.

Right now, I'm using a apex:input "text field" and using the date.parse function to convert it into a date before assigning to the sobject's field before I save it to the database.

Is this the correct way of doing it? or is there an easier workaround?

```
<apex:page controller="contExtBkup" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.D2DCalendar, '/calendar.js')}" />
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.D2DCalendar, '/calendar.css')}"/>


<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                     <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.contact.fields.birthdate.label}"  />
                      <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                      <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredBlock" />
                            <apex:inputtext id="birthdate"   
                                            rendered="{!NOT(dobOp)}"
                                            value="{!contact.birthdate}"
                                            onfocus="initialiseCalendar(this,'{!$Component.birthdate}')"/>

                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!dobOp}">
                                <apex:inputtext id="birthdate1" styleClass="error"  

                                            value="{!contact.birthdate}"
                                            onfocus="initialiseCalendar(this,'{!$Component.birthdate1}')"/>

                                <div class="errorMsg"><strong>Error:</strong>&nbsp;{!dob_error}</div>

                            </apex:outputPanel>
                         </apex:outputPanel>
                  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
                   </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}"  />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>     

 </apex:pageblock>    


 </apex:form>
```

Note    I'm including an inline Javascript calendar here

Controller:

```
 //SPN
 public with sharing class contExtBkup {
 public boolean dobOp{get;set;}
 public string dob_Error{get;set;}
 public Contact contact{get;set;}


 public contExtBkup() {
        dobOp=false;   
        if(this.contact == null)
            this.contact = new Contact();
}

public pageReference next(){

    if (contact.birthdate == null){
        dobOp=true;
        dob_Error = 'Please enter date';

    }
     else if (contact.birthdate >= date.today()){
            dobOp=true;
            dob_Error='DOB cant be current/future date';
                       /*string date1 = contact.Birthdate.format();
            contact.Birthdate = date.parse(date1);
            contact.Birthdate = date.parse('07/31/2015'); */
    }                
     else{
           dobOp=false;
           dob_Error='';
         }  
  return page.datePickerJS;
}
```

[image]}

I have added the error message too...How to change this format to something like MM/DD/YYYY so that I don't get the error message about converting text to date.

Comment: Give a try to your date format something like this - MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: any reason why you are not using `<apex:inputField>` tag?

Comment: @Prabhat - Right, that's what I tried in my controller code,    string date1 = contact.Birthdate.format();
                contact.Birthdate = date.parse(date1);

                return page.datePickerJS;  but it's still not working.

Comment: @AAU - I'm getting the above problem when I use apex:inputfield tag. Hence, I had to use apex:input as an alternative but I'm asking in this forum if someone has run into this issue and if so, is there an acceptable workaround

Comment: I even tried hardcoding the date as '07/31/2015' just to see what would happen, but it always convert into Jul 31 2015 00:00:00 this format.

Comment: You really should be using apex:inputField bound to an sobject field of type date; the VF page will only allow entry of valid date formats. Your apex controller code can be used to test for ranges.  You can use 'proxy' sobjects in your controller if the user-entered date isn't intended to be saved as part of some DML operation.

Comment: Can you post your code? adding `type="date"` to your <apex:input> should take care of the format.

Comment: @AAU - I've pasted the code above. Please take a look and advise.

Comment: @crop1645 - Do you have any suggestions on it? If this is the right way or is there an alternate correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your inputtext to inputField, then it will work. In this case you would not need the onfocus="initialiseCalendar(...)"

```
<apex:inputField id="birthdate"   
                      rendered="{!NOT(dobOp)}"
                      value="{!contact.birthdate}"/>
```

Otherwise, if you want to use a custom date picker, then change your inputtext to input and add type="date"

```
<apex:input id="birthdate"
                   type="date"
                   rendered="{!NOT(dobOp)}"
                   value="{!contact.birthdate}"
                   onfocus="initialiseCalendar(this,'{!$Component.birthdate}')"/>
```

Comment: That's what I have done, but I'm not really sure if it's the "correct" way to do it. - like what @crop1645 said. Hence, I wanted to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Use [Date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) class of Apex.
That will help.

You can use it like this:-

**Controller**

```
public class ControllerForDate {
    public Time useDate {get; set;}
    public ControllerForDate()
    {
        if (useDate == null) {
           useDate =  DateTime.now().date();
    }
}
```

In Page, use this:-

```
<apex:input type="date" value="{!useDate}"/>
```